# Get original URL after mod rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, uri

How to get both original and changes URL after mod rewrite?

Adress:

```
http://www.example.com/abcd
```

rewritten into this using [L] rewrite

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?cat=abcd
```

Tried:

```
echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
echo $_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"];
```

Both with the same result

```
/abcd
```

Would like to know not only the /abcd but also http://www.example.com/index.php?cat=abcd

Rewriting is working since i can find variable named cat filled with abcd in PHP

Comment: Why do you need the non-rewritten URL?

Comment: Do you need the *actual* URL? If you don't need the GET variables you can use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

Comment: wanted it for some debug and testing

Comment: It's just not possible.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Comment: this will give the last page the user visited and referred to the current page, hence "referrer". note the spelling to reveal the fuel behind PHP ;)

Comment: @Nick yeah! PHP spells it this way.  :-/